# HTML Select field calls web services through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I have some modal with forms where I create object to store into database.
In these forms I have a Select field like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id=existingUser>
    <label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
        style="width: 100%;" th:field="*{user}">
        <option th:each="user: ${users}" th:value="${user.username}"
            th:text="${user.username}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

where users is passed from Controller with Model. With this approach I have to update all page to refresh the values inside select field otherwise I can only update the table where I show the new created object but I can't use the new field in select.
The problems are the performance and the look refreshing page, furthermore I can't use these instruction to show my message

```
location.reload();
//reload only the tag with id carsTable, so only the table
//$('#carsTable').load(document.URL +  ' #carsTable');
$('#addCarModal').modal("hide");
notifyMessage("Your car has been created!", 'success');

function notifyMessage(textMessage, typeMessage){
    $.bootstrapGrowl(textMessage, {
        type: typeMessage, // (null, 'info', 'error', 'success')
    });
}
```

Is there a way to call ajax when modal is called? Or can I pass data from javascript to HTML (if I retrive values when add button is clicked).
Sometimes I also check if select field are empty and in this case show a message inside the modals instead form.Thanks

UPDATE. I thouth this code:

To start with only success manage:

```
function freeUserController($scope) {
   $http.get("https://localhost:8080/users/")
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.users = data;          
    });
}
```

in my html page:

```
<div ng-controller="freeUserController" class="form-group" id=existingUser>
    <label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
        style="width: 100%;" name="user">
        <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.username}}">
        {{user.username}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are rendering the HTML on the server. There is probably no way to make it re-render just that element. However, there are different ways you can do this:

One, you could start using client-side MVC / rendering like Angular.js. That way, you could automatically refresh the select field when a new field is added.

Two, you could put the new option into the select field without using an MVC system. That would require uncoupling the data from the view, so I wouldn't recommend it. However, you *could* have the submit button perform an ajax call to make sure the server reacted correctly, and only add the new option when the server response has arrived. Your code would look something like this:

```
$.ajax(url).done(function(){
    $('#my-select').append('<option>').html('your data')
}).fail(function(){
    // show error message...
});
```

Comment: A workaround might be use javascript to write html as in your example but I would have a lot of replied code.
I have never used angularjs but I know that it can create a dynamic binding, Can I insert ajax call into angularjs controller?

Comment: Yes, AngularJS has a lot of AJAX functionality. It even has its own AJAX function wrapper: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I update with a possible code to refresh select field, is it the right way? How can it know when refresh?

Comment: It looks like you're on the right path. The view should update automatically when the underlying data model changes. Just check the AngularJS documentation for details.